# Is drawing a hidden weapon a free action with the Watching Taldor (On guard) trait?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Drawing a weapon is a move action, while drawing a hidden weapon is typically a standard action.

The trait Watching Taldor (also known as On guard in pfsrd) allows one to draw a weapon as a free action under certain circumstances. Does it also apply to drawing hidden weapons?

---

One way to think of this is: Both the trait and the rule for drawing hidden weapons (found under the sleight of hand skill) are special cases of drawing weapons. Which trumps the other?

Another way to think of this is: Does the trait apply to *draw a weapon* action, which is different from the *draw a hidden weapon* action, or the general act of drawing a weapon regardless of its hiddenness?

Answer (score 1):

A hidden weapon is slower to draw than a normal weapon (standard action instead of move action).

An ability that talks about increasing speed of drawing a weapon is addressing the normal, latter case. Watching Taldor just speeds up drawing a normal weapon from move to free.  Other abilities, like the ninja's Hidden Weapons trick, allows you to draw hidden weapons as a move action.

So RAW Watching Taldor doesn't help with hidden weapons.  As a GM I would tend to rule that this is in general a "speed track," with various situations and abilities bumping the speed up or down a notch. Draw a weapon? Move.  Draw hidden weapon? Standard. Draw hidden with Watching Taldor?  We'll say a move.  Drawing a hidden weapon with Watching Taldor and Hidden Weapons? Free, sure.

Comment: Can you expand on why this part is true: "An ability that talks about increasing speed of drawing a weapon is addressing the normal, latter case." ?

Comment: Because "hidden weapon" is a more specific case in the rules?

Comment: But that is the question: The trait is also more specific than the general rules for drawing weapons. The trait does not specify non-hidden weapons. What is the general principle from which you deduce that the trait does not apply to hidden weapons?

Comment: Because hidden weapons is more specific than general weapons, and also using good judgement because the alternate interpretation doesn't make sense in light of the other relevant abilities.  There is no "purely legally correct answer" in this case so you have to use some context.

Comment: Please consider adding the lack of purely legally correct answer to your answer, possibly with arguments as to why that is so.